# What is the max resolution for the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter driver under Win 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, adobe, screen-resolution

First, a bunch of preamble, then the question is 7 paragraphs down.

I have a user that we recently upgraded to an Intel NUC 8 w/ the integrated Radeon Vega M graphics. The machine also has the on-chip Intel HD 630 graphics, but it's not hooked up to any of the various HDMI/DP ports on the machine, it's only used internally for some of the hw acceleration that it knows how to do.

The machine is being used in our print shop, doing large-ish (24"x36" @ 720dpi) jobs on a couple of wide carriage Epson printers. Printing is done directly from Photoshop CC 2018. The machine is running Win 10 Pro and is completely up to date at the time of this posting.

Yesterday, I moved the machine into its new home and discovered I still needed to install the right graphics driver in order to drive 3 monitors. All previous machine setup had occurred w/ a single monitor and the Radeon graphics card was driven w/ the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter driver. I downloaded the driver package from Intel and installed it and got all the connected displays up and running.

Today, I received complaints of Photoshop CC 2018 running extremely slowly when trying to print. Some research on Adobe forums revealed many users experiencing severe slowness when trying to print. The item that all reports have in common is that they're using AMD graphics cards and running the AMD driver with a version later than 17.10.1.

I was able to replicate the behavior that others had found. If I uninstall all the AMD Radeon driver/software and run on the MS Basic Display Adapter driver, Photoshop runs like a champ. However, the machine is back to one monitor.

The display adapter in my machine is too new to have support in any of the driver versions that other Photoshop users had found worked for them. I verified this by going on a scavenger hunt for the device IDs in Radeon driver packages from the end of 2017. Adobe forum users started posting about the Radeon/Photoshop interaction in April of 2018. Here's a decent thread if you're interested - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2474200

Ultimately this looks like a problem that AMD or Adobe need to fix. As soon as either or both of those companies release new versions that fix the glitch, I'll happily install them. In the meantime, my guy still needs to be able to do his job. In order to do that, I'm considering taking his 3x monitor setup away and giving him a single very large monitor.

HERE'S THE QUESTION -

What's the maximum resolution that the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter driver supports? I know it'll do 1920x1080 but I'm thinking of getting something much larger, like 3440x1440. Will the MS BDA support that resolution? I'm 100% aware that I won't get all the fancy GPU acceleration features and whatnot. I'm not happy about that but I'll live with it for a while if that's what has to happen. Can I shop for big monitors, or do I need to come up with another plan?

Comment: Well, _my_ solution was to buy NVIDIA. But that may or may not work for you.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the BDA uses the GPU like a framebuffer, which means you should be able to get whatever the highest resolution your monitor reports as supported that fits a standard aspect ratio and will fit in your GPU memory.